# Node.js delete request

Tags: node.js, express

I have a node.js application with Express for routing and Mongoose for the database access.

I have this HTTP DELETE request that is deleting an entry in the database if certain requirements are met.

```
    .delete(function (req, res) {

    Movie.findOne({_id: req.params.id

    }, function (err, movie) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        for (var i = 0, len = movie.actors.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (movie.actors[i].actor == "Chuck Norris"){
                res.status(403).send({ message: 'Cannot delete Chuck Norris' });
              }
            else {
                Movie.remove({_id: req.params.id
                }, function (err, movie) {
                    if (err)
                        res.send(err);

                    res.json({message: 'Movie deleted'});
                });


    }
        }

    });

});
```

If I send a HTTP DELETE with the ID of a film, it will check in the actors list if Chuck Norris is in the movie and I will prevent the deletion if he is there.

The problem is that my console is returning me this error :

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

So I presume that this an issue with my callbacks. Due to the asynchronus nature of node.js the "slow" database call made that my .delete sent the headers before the findOne finished ?

How can I manage to validate before deletion and send a proper http error code if the deletion is not possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful when you respond to a request multiple times in the same scope like that. On error you should prepend `return` to `res.send(err)` so that execution will not continue further. The same goes for your `res.status()` in the for-loop.

Comment: I changed it to a return and tweaked the rest a little bit and it works now. Thanks !